# Uploading the gradle artifact to Nexus 3.41 using azure DevOps

Tags: gradle, curl, nexus, artifact, azure-devops-extensions

i am Using cURL upload extension to upload the artifact to Nexus repository.

I am getting the below error

[image: 1]

Upload artifact to nexus extension is not supporting to Nexus 3.41 server

Answer (score 0):

According to the screenshot, it seems task was complete. The warning: Not all files were uploaded.

You could try to create a new repo and use the specific file to upload with a new service connection. Make sure the "Remote Directory" is available.

Comment: Curl -T <file.zip> -u username: password +X POST 'https nexus repo server url'.   I am trying to upload a file from command line. file.zip is available in my Linux vm. I am pushing the file from Linux to nexus repository by using curl command. I am getting error 405 method not allowed.